# CUDA Matrix Copy

Tags: cuda

I have been trying to understand thread and block indexing pattern in simple matrix copy example 
http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/

Why do we use TILE_DIM as a stride while calculating y since we know that our Block size is (TILE_DIM * BLOCK_ROWS). Besides we are amortizing the calculation by forcing each thread to do TILE_DIM / BLOCK_ROWS copies. I tried considering Threads Per Block as (4,1) and Blocks Per Grid as (2,2) with square matrix width as 8. I find that the offset values created also go beyond 15 which is above the matrix linear (1D) dimensions. Kindly help using an example if possible. I would like to see some links tutorial on Matrix tiling with amortization explained in detail.

```
const int TILE_DIM = 32;
const int BLOCK_ROWS = 8;

__global__ void copy(float *odata, const float *idata)
{
  int x = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;
  int width = gridDim.x * TILE_DIM;

  for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j+= BLOCK_ROWS)
  odata[(y+j)*width + x] = idata[(y+j)*width + x];
}

...

const int nx = 1024;
const int ny = 1024;

dim3 dimGrid(nx/TILE_DIM, ny/TILE_DIM, 1);
dim3 dimBlock(TILE_DIM, BLOCK_ROWS, 1);

....

copy<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>( ... );
```

Comment: Many thanks talonmies for updating the code. My apologies for not putting the relevant code in proper form. I am still not able get how exactly threads are working during the copy per element basis.

Comment: Concerning your own example, how much did you choose `TILE_DIM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do we use `TILE_DIM` as a stride while calculating `y` since we know that our block size is `TILE_DIM * BLOCK_ROWS`.

According to your code, you are "tiling" your `1024x1024` matrix into `32x32` tiles, each of `32x32` elements. This is done by defining the grid size by

```
dim3 dimGrid(nx/TILE_DIM, ny/TILE_DIM, 1);
```

Also, you are partitioning each tile in `4` subtiles of size `8x32` each. This is done by defining the block size by

```
dim3 dimBlock(TILE_DIM, BLOCK_ROWS, 1);
```

Each block should copy an entire tile, as you noticed. By resorting to the definitions of `x` and `y`, rewrite the index `(y+j)*width + x` as

```
y*width + j*width + x = 
    (blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM)*width + blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM +
    (j+threadIdx.y)*width + threadIdx
```

The first term `(blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM)*width + blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM` identifies the matrix element with index `(blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM, blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM)` which in turn is the uppermost element of the tile identified by `blockIdx.x` and `blockIdx.y`. The second element `(j+threadIdx.y)*width + threadIdx.x` identifies the element with index `threadIdx.x,j+threadIdx.y` within the generic tile. Now, consider that `threadIdx.x` ranges between `0` and `TILE_DIM-1`, while `threadIdx.y` ranges within `0` and `BLOCK_ROWS`. This explains why you need the `for` loop so that `j+threadIdx.y` can span the whole interval `(0,TILE_DIM-1)`.

Comment: Many thanks JackOLantern, I understand clearly now how it works. Just to clarify regarding the (j+threadIdx.y , threadIdx.x) index part, does this index refers the TILE_DIM/BLOCK_ROWS number of columnar elements of the matrix?

Comment: In the `(j+threadIdx.y, threadIdx.x)` index, `(threadIdx.y , threadIdx.x)` addresses a specific element of the sub-tile, while `j` addresses the sub-tile, so that it acts as an offset. You have to imagine that one sub-tile, corresponding for example to `j=1` is on top of the sub-tile corresponding to `j=2`. In this way, `threadIdx.y` is a "relative" row index within the generic sub-tile, while `j+threadIdx.y` is an "absolute" row index within the generic tile. For the columns, you have only an "absolute" column index `threadIdx.x` since you have sub-tiling only along the rows.

Comment: I gather that we amortize our calculations by taking our block size 1/4th of the TILE size. But alongside, we also provide coalesced access using this method. Is my view correct?